# Get domain chosen by PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory

I'm creating a custom login functionality for asp.net which validates against active directory. The user must be able to login with only his username or with his username and a domain (and a password in both cases).

Code:

```
AuthUser user = Authentication.getDomainAndUserName(givenUsername);

bool validAccount = false;

PrincipalContext network = null;
if (user.domain != "") network = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, user.domain);
else network = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

if (UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(network, IdentityType.SamAccountName, user.username) != null) {
      validAccount = network.ValidateCredentials(givenUsername, givenPassword, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
}
```

The "AuthUser" contains the username and, if given, the domain. Now if a user didn't explicitly specify the domain the above still works fine.

So if you call

```
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
```

It seems that the domain is set automatically.

**In that case, how can i find out the domain it used?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always can get the domain used from the user principal returned from UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity()

Comment: got it by 
`UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(network, IdentityType.SamAccountName, user.username);`

`string distinguishedName = userPrincipal.DistinguishedName`
now. Then extracted and joined all "DC" parts of that string to get the full domain.

Comment: In case you still need the answer: it's defined in my original question by "network = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, user.domain);"